# Common elements in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

I have a list of CSV's , which I am currently reading in a dataframe in Pandas. I need to find the common elements in one of columns of a dataframe.

```
 df1 = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
 df2 = pd.read_csv("example1.csv")
 val = np.intersect1d(example[' column'], example1[' column'])
```

How can I do it for multiple files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to find common elements for all pairs in a list of files or the elements that can be found in all files? (You can [edit] your question to include the info)

Comment: you can also use inner merge of pandas' dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, "A"),
    (1, "B"),
    (2, "C"),
    (3, "D")
], columns=["id", "val"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, "A"),
    (1, "A"),
    (2, "A"),
    (3, "D")
], columns=["id", "val"])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, "A"),
    (1, "A"),
    (2, "A"),
    (3, "A")
], columns=["id", "val"])

from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

val = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: np.intersect1d(acc, x['val']),
    dfs,
    dfs[0]['val']
)

val

#  array(['A'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) on multiple sets via unpacking an iterable. Data from @raulferreira.

```
res = set.intersection(*(set(df['val']) for df in [df1, df2, df3]))

print(res)
# {'A'}
```